# ruby on rails - bundler problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, rubygems

i have tried to install the rake gems with bundler and got the following messege:

```
C:\Users\M4L\Documents\ex_projects\ror\first_project>bundle install
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.org/.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most
likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For

information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To connect without
using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
```

I have tried both solutions:

1) the gem source was `http://rubygems.org/` and not `https://rubygems.org/` the gem fetcher works fine. only the bundler fetcher doesn't work.

2)i tried to install the ca certificates needed for ssl ---- downloaded cacert.pem from  `http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem` ,put it on c:\railsinstaller and adjusted the environment variables

```
set SSL_CERT_FILE = c:\railsinstaller\cacert.pem
```

and also adjusted them in the control panel.
all of this did not work

3) I tried to download all the specified gems in the gem.lock file menually by gem install 
-- this also did not work. as somehow there is another gem list related to bundle install

4)i changed my .gemrc file and added the line :ssl_verify_mode: 0

5)if I new the source that bundler relates to I could have changed it to http://rubygems.org / - but I do not know it

so I still cannot migrate my database.

what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was a real beginner..
it needed to change the https to http in the gem.lock and the gemfile and i changed it only in gem.lock

basically the problem happens because i was subscripted to limited(screened) internet (named :"internet rimon") which made problems with ssl.